# If the order of 3 modulo $p$ is $q$, why are $1, 3, 3^2, ..., 3^{q-1}$ all distinct (mod $p$)?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

Really confused on going about proving this. I know $1,3,3^2,...3^{q-1}$ can't be congruent to $1$ mod $p$, as that would imply the order isn't $q$. But I'm not sure how to go about showing these numbers are distinct mod $p$.

Answer (score 1):

Because if $3^i \equiv 3^j$ where $1<i<j<q$, then $3^{j-i} \equiv 1$ would contradict the fact that $q$ is the smallest positive integer with $3^q \equiv 1$.